# How do $digest loop invoked by angular when an event fires?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was trying to understand the in and out of angularjs.

I come across $digest loop, $watch lists etc, however my doubt is when an event fires at browser (Button click) how do angular knows it? In javascript if we subscribed to an event then, we get notification when the event fires. How do angular get those notification to invoke the $digest loop.(Please note that I am not trying to understand about ng-click directive.)

I tried google it, but I did not get the details. Any URLs or book name is just fine.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Angular docs about **Scope Life Cycle**:

> When the browser calls into JavaScript the code executes outside the
>   Angular execution context, which means that Angular is unaware of
>   model modifications. To properly process model modifications the
>   execution has to enter the Angular execution context using the $apply
>   method. Only model modifications which execute inside the $apply
>   method will be properly accounted for by Angular. For example if a
>   directive listens on DOM events, such as ng-click it must evaluate the
>   expression inside the $apply method.

To make sure Angular evaluates the `$scope` modifications, you need to use the built-in in handlers: `ng-click`, `$timeout`, etc. After executing the handler, Angular will make sure to perform a dirty check and update the DOM if necessary. The `$scope.$apply()` is called automatically.

In other cases, when using handlers not related with Angular: `setTimeout()`, `document.body.addEventListener()`, etc. the developer should take care by himself about dirty check, by calling manually `$scope.$apply()` in the handler.

For example:

*1) Automatic dirty check by Angular* (the recommended and correct way)

```
angular.module('App').controller('Ctrl', function($timeout) {
  $scope.myText = 'Initial text';
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.myText = 'Initial text after 1 second';
    //$scope.$apply() is called automatically
  }, 1000);
});
```

*2) Manually evaluate the scope changes*

```
angular.module('App').controller('Ctrl', function($timeout) {
  $scope.myText = 'Initial text';
  setTimeout(function() {
    $scope.myText = 'Initial text after 1 second';
    $scope.$apply(); // should be called manually
  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The magic here generally happens in the `ng-click` directive (or one if it's related directives like `ng-mouseenter`, `ng-mouseleave`, `ng-keypress`, etc.)

Looking at the source, the directive simply registers a callback for the appropriate event using angular's `JQLite` (i.e. `element.on(event, callback)`).  The callback itself executes the expression in the correct scope via `$scope.$apply` (which starts the digest loop).

If you are going to register your own event listeners outside of the normal angular directives, you'll want to follow the same pattern they use.

The [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L41) is remarkably simple to read and is worth having a look at.

Comment: Ohh.. Inside ng-click directive's compile function they are wiring the events, and from there they kick start the $apply. That make sense to me. Thank you.